# MSCAPI Certificate selection box in Java; SunMSCAPI?

Tags: java, pki, client-certificates, mscapi

I'm experimenting with the relatively new SunMSCAPI security provider. I want to build a simple applet that prompts the browser to pop up the certificate selection box. I'll take it from there.
I have Googled this up one way and down another. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I am working (struggling) on something similar - although for a non web app.. The only solution which has worked for me so far - is to do a JNI to C# (Wrapped using MCPP)..

Comment: I want to try and avoid JNI. I'm hoping the new SunMSCAPI JCE would be able to do that without using going JNI.

Comment: @luckylak i know this is old, but I am trying to accomplish the same thing as you did. How did you use JNI to call on the windows certificate store and windows certificate selection GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SunMSCAPI` provider to instantiate the local client windows keystore. You can do it simply using this code:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY",new SunMSCAPI());
keyStore.load(null, null);
```

Or if you prefer you can add the provider to security list instead of passing it to the `getInstance()` call:

```
SunMSCAPI providerMSCAPI = new SunMSCAPI();
Security.addProvider(providerMSCAPI);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, null);
```

Note that it's probably already added by default to security providers list for java installation on windows OS.

There are not many details on your question so I give you an example to for example show all aliases and subject of the related certificates from the local client windows keystore to illustrate the use of this provider:

```
package org.catcert.crypto.keyStoreImpl.windows;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY",new SunMSCAPI());
        keyStore.load(null, null);

        // copy to avoid concurrent problems with aliases...
        ArrayList<String> aliases = Collections.list(keyStore.aliases());
        for(String alias : aliases){
            System.out.println("keyEntry alias: " + alias);
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
            System.out.println("Certificate subject: " +  cert.getSubjectDN());

        }
    }
}
```

*Note that SunMSCAPI was introduced on java 1.6, however support for 64 bits version was added on java 1.7.*